# In actionPerformed repaint doesn't work with new Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, label

After I press a button, `actionPerformed` is called. A start a new `Thread` like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mylabel.setText("new text");
                    mylabel.revalidate();
                    mylabel.repaint();
                } catch (Exception x) {
                    x.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.start();
        MyFunction();

    // ...
```

After that on `myLabel` the string, `new text`, does not appear, just after `actionPerformed` run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run GUI related code in Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). Do not create another thread.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable() {
                ...
```

If `actionPerformed` is the listener callback, it already runs on EDT. Create another
`Runnable` if the callback takes long to execute, or it will "slow down" the GUI.

If `MyFunction()` method is not related to GUI repaint or anything like that,
run it on another thread, specially if it is resource intensive.